# Javascript setUTCMonth does not work for November

Tags: javascript, utc

I'm getting some really strange behaviour with Javascript date objects.

```
var t = new Date();
t.setUTCFullYear(2014);
t.setUTCMonth(10);
t.setUTCDate(20);
console.log(t);
```

This returns:
    Date {Sat Dec 20 2014 10:26:23 GMT-0800 (PST)}

Whereas if you use `t.setMonth(10)`, you correctly get November. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work as expected tomorrow.

Today (October 31st), `t` is initialized with its day as `31`. When you set the month to November, you're setting "November 31st", which is corrected to December 1st.

Then you set the date to `20`, but the month has already changed. Set the date first, or better yet, use the two-argument verson of `setUTCMonth()`:

```
t.setUTCMonth(10, 20);
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm missing something (EDIT: I was, [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26681426/74757) covers it), but you're right. However, this works:

```
var t = new Date();
t.setUTCFullYear(2014);
t.setUTCMonth(10, 20); // Set day here instead
console.log(t); // Thu Nov 20 2014 12:40:42 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
```

It also works if you switch the order of the set statements:

```
var t = new Date();
t.setUTCFullYear(2014);
t.setUTCDate(20);
t.setUTCMonth(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a mixture of particular dates and the order of setting individual parts of the date. If you step through what's happening it becomes clearer:

- New date is initialised as today: Oct 31, 2014
- Setting the year to 2014: no effect
- Setting the month to November: Nov 31, 2014 is interpreted as Dec 1, 2014
- Setting the date to 20: Dec 20, 2014